# Mock consumers interface in subscribe method

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock two consumer interfaces inside subscribe method

ConsumerService.java

```
  @Autowired
  ConsumerDao consumerDao;
  
  public void insertStatus(){
  
  SchedularStatus schedularStatus = new SchedularStatus();
  Mono<Object> savedConsumer =  consumerDao.save(schedularStatus);
  savedConsumer.subscribe(success -> Log.info("consumer data saved")),
            (error-> Log.error("Error while saving schedular data));" 
}
```

Below Junit test code I have tried

ConsumerServiceTest.java

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ConsumerServiceTest {
 
@InjectMock
ConsumerService consumerService;

@Mock
Mono<Object> mono;

@Mock
ConsumerDao consumerDao;

@Test
void testInsertStatus(){

Mockito.when(consumerDao.save(any(SchedularStatus))).thenReturn(mono);
doAnswer(answer -> {
  Consumer<Object> consumer1 = answer.getArgument(0);
  Consumer<Object> consumer2 = answer.getArgument(1);
  consumer1.accept(new Object());
  consumer2.accept(new Object());
  return null;
    }).when(mono).subscribe(any(Consumer.class), any(Consumer.class));
  Mockto.verify(consumerDao).save(any(SchedularStatus.class));
}
```

But I am getting Nullpointer Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException : errorConsumer
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Ojbects.java:228)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4278)
```

Comment: What are you testing? You mock `consumerDao.save` and then verify that it has been called?

Comment: And why don't you use a real Mono instance? Avoids all the problems with setting up the mock correctly

Comment: And why would a Mono call both of its subscribers? It cannot be successful and failed at the same time

Comment: @knittl, PFB your answers to your both questions.
1. `verify(consumerDao).save` is not called because it is failing at `when(mono).subscribe(any(Consumer.class), any(Consumer.class));`. On inspecting `any(Consumer.class)`, its value is coming as null and thus throwing NPE.
2. I used `Mono<Object> emptyMono = Mono.create();`. But I got error argument passed to when() is not a mock.

Comment: @knittl, The source code is existing and i was asked to write junit for this method. 
Do you know why NPE is coming and what should i do to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mock non-service classes. Mocking `Mono`s or `Optional`s or `CompletableFuture`s almost always leads to problems (I have also seen real test code which created and set up mocks for `List`s and `Map`s). Simply return a real instance:

```
Mockito.when(consumerDao.save(any(SchedularStatus)))
        .thenAnswer(a -> Mono.just(new Object()));
```

And a second test which sets up the mock to return a failed Mono (`Mono.error(new Exception())`).

But then again, your test is not really testing anything (or performing very questionable actions), because:

1. You mock the method that you are verifying
2. Your mocked mono is successful and failed at the same time
3. You are never calling a method on your class under test
4. Your consumers don't do anything really, so why bother calling them?

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE comes from your mock configuration :

```java
doAnswer(answer -> {
  Consumer<Object> consumer1 = answer.getArgument(0);
  Consumer<Object> consumer2 = answer.getArgument(1);
  consumer1.accept(new Object());
  consumer2.accept(new Object());
  return null; // You return null instead of a valid Disposable
    }).when(mono).subscribe(any(Consumer.class), any(Consumer.class));
```

`subscribe` method return a `Disposable`. You have to provide one.

Comment: I mocked `Mock Disposable disposable` But I got again NPE.